# Finding an attribute of an element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the attribute of an element in jquery, but it keeps returning undefined.
This is the HTML I have,

```
<div class="item-image-wrapper">
  <a href="/Money-Headphones-item?id=283751750">
    <img title="Money Headphones" alt="Money Headphones" class="original-image" 
       src="http://t2.rbxcdn.com/ef3e40344e3d5fd021f94aaa71593c76">
    <img src="http://images.rbxcdn.com/b84cdb8c0e7c6cbe58e91397f91b8be8.png" alt="New">
   </a>
</div>
```

Firstly, how would I use jquery to find the "a" element because it has no name, then how would I find the second image of "a" and alert the attribute "alt"

I currently have:

```
$(data).find("a").find("img:eq(1)").attr("alt")
```

but it doesnt work.
Can someone help please.

Comment: Maybe posting more code (specifically parents of `<a`>) will help us in helping you better.

Comment: Can you use the href attribute for identification? What about div.item-image-wrapper > a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) is  0-based indexing,

Use

```
$(data).find("a").find("img:eq(0)").attr("alt")
```

However you can use child selector and no need to use `:eq()` as you have only 1 `img` element

```
$(data).find("a > img").attr("alt")
```

Comment: *"...as you have only 1 img element"* It would be fine with more than one as well, provided you just wanted the attribute from the first one.

Comment: Thanks.. YAYAYAYAYAYAYYAAYA

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("a > img").attr("alt")
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Remember the anchor tag has no name. Just a href

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `:first`

```
$(data).find("a").find("img:first").attr("src")
```

[Jsbin](https://jsbin.com/cinagitiqe/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Thanks you Very mcuch